# Parallel with withPool

Tags: concurrency, groovy, parallel-processing, gpars

I found an example on how to use `withPool`. It says I just need to add the word `Parallel` to Groovy's methods like `collect, find, each`, put it into `withPool` and it executes the code parallel.

```
import static groovyx.gpars.GParsPool.withPool

list = 1..1000000

withPool{
    squares = list.collectParallel { it * it}
}
println squares
```

Is there any chance to check if it's really parallel?
I tried a benchmark test with the same code but the sequential way
and the parallel way was much more slowly.

Comment: I've improved my description a bit.

Comment: You can view **CPU Useage** of **Windows Task Manager**.
So, CPU Useage can up to 100 % when processing heavy tasks in parallel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by *'but sequential and the parallel way was much more slowly'*...

This will run in parallel, but for this simplistic example, the extra cost of firing off jobs to other processors and handling the ordering of results will probably end up taking longer than just multiplying some numbers

For a simplistic example showing it working, you can do:

```
import static groovyx.gpars.GParsPool.withPool

list = [ 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 ]

withPool{
    result = list.collectParallel {
        Thread.sleep( it * 1000 )
        it
    }
}
println result
```

So result should be `[2,2,2,2,2]`, but the `collectParallel` should finish in less than the 10 seconds you'd expect with the serial `collect` version

Obviously this depends on you having more than one core ;-)

Comment: It sounds strange to me.